# WI-Fi Calling Notification keeps coming back

Tags: iphone, wifi, notifications, facetime

This notification keeps appearing on my Mac running Mac OS X 10.13.6 (17G65):

[image: Notification that Wi-Fi calling is available]

> **Wi-Fi Calling**
>   You can use your phone number to make and receive calls directly on this Mac using Wi-Fi.

I have:

1. Clicked "Not Now"
2. Clicked "Turn On"
3. On my Mac: Turned off *all* notifications for FaceTime
4. On my Mac: Logged out of FaceTime
5. On my iPhone: Went to "Settings" » "Phone" » "Wi-Fi Calling" and turned ***off*** "Add Wi-Fi Calling for Other Devices"
6. On my iPhone: Went to "Settings" » "Phone" » "Wi-Fi Calling" and turned ***off*** "Calls on Other Devices"

Still, after all of that, **the notification keeps coming back every few minutes**.

Any ideas how to kill this thing?

I tried Google but all of the results were about turning this feature *on*, not *off*.

Answer (score 3):

The answer appears to have been this:

Turn *on* the feature on my iPhone.

Wait awhile.

Turn *off* the feature on my iPhone.

Reboot the Macs that were showing the notifications.

One of those things made it go away.

Answer (score 2):

My Mac kept nagging after configuring a new iPhone. Despite turning WiFi calling on on the Mac, and rebooting, the nags kept re-appearing.

What finally caused a stop was updating my E911 emergency contact on the phone. No more Mac nags!

Answer (score 1):

I recently upgraded to the iPhone 12mini (from iPhone 6s) and was receiving this issue. After some poking around, here's how I was able to solve it:

- Sign out of iMessage / FaceTime on your old iPhone.

  - *Or more drastic, erase all content and settings from your old iPhone.*
- Sign out then sign back in to iMessage and FaceTime on your new iPhone.
- Authenticate / allow wifi calling from new iPhone.